# how to limit max zoomOut when a button is clicked in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, zooming

I know how to maximise the zoom features using orbitcontrols, however what is the best way of stopping the zoom after a button is clicked.

```
var zoomOut = function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(zoomOut);
    var i = camera.position.z;
    while (i < controls.minDistance) {
        i += 0.003
        console.log(i)
    }
};
```

that is what i have set for now but i can not get i to increment.
I have also tried setting i++ but this did not work either

any feedback is grateful

Comment: Did you already used the `.maxDistance` in your controls? [Reference](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls.maxDistance) . I think you can use a function to set this property to `infinity` or the numerical value depending on the user interaction with the button.

Comment: ```controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

    controls.minDistance = 1.2;

    controls.maxDistance = 3;```

that is what i have set and when i zoomOut i want the frame to stop at 3, maybe i should look at using dollyout and dollyin instead.

Comment: I did not got why your code does not accept simple controls.maxDistance = 3. Maybe you should inform further explanation about how you would like to make the routine. Here it is an example I made in code pen and works fine for me. Maybe that would be a solution for you.
[https://codepen.io/ferrari212/pen/bGBpRrN](https://codepen.io/ferrari212/pen/bGBpRrN)